# how to transform button after hover again when muosedown and release

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've a button with `transform: none;` when I active that button the transform changed to  `transform: scale(0.9);`. that's clear.
What I do? I want to change transform to 0 when hover out that button, but transform again when I hover again that button to 0.9.
**Screen1: I don't want that one:**

[image]

**Screen2: I want that one:**
[image: I want that one:]

My Code:

```css
button{
  width: 180px;
  height: 80px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform: none;
  background-color: #3a3b3c;
}
button:active{
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<button>Filters</button>
```

Comment: probably going to need a way to track the state of the button being activated. Could use js or a checkbox label.

Comment: Please see the facbook Like button to understand me

Comment: change :active with :hover ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this gonna make you happy?  <3 jQuery!

*First we gonna check if the button is clicked or not. And if clicked, change the var so we know it's has changed.*

*`var isclicked = false; $('button').click(function(e){ isclicked = true; });`*

*Then the `.mouseout` function, because you want the change to only take place when the mouse leaves the button. If I understand your question correctly. And only when the button is clicked. Therefor that previous click check. Last, `.addClass` function so we can style to the desired behavior.*

*`$('button').mouseout(function(e){  if(isclicked == true) { $('button').addClass('activated'); }  });`*

*&*

*`button.activated:hover { transform: scale(0.9); }`*

**Full code snippet:**

```js
var isclicked = false;
$('button').click(function(e){
  isclicked = true;
});
$('button').mouseout(function(e){
  if(isclicked == true) {
    $('button').addClass('activated');
   }
});
```

```css
button{
  width: 180px;
  height: 80px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  transform: none;
  transition:all 0.2s;
  background-color: #3a3b3c;
}
button:active{
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
button.activated:hover{
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Filters</button>
```

Comment: Everything is working fine. but when I click the button, the second time when I hover the button I want to transfer 0 again as the first time,

Comment: I don't want to transform 0.9 at the mouse hover!

Comment: set it to `scale(1);` or what ever style you want? Please be more clear..

Comment: See the (Close) button on this link: https://web.facebook.com/privacy/dialog/privacy_center/ads I want this please.

Answer (score 0):

So I created two functions for you, hopefully this works for you! In your button tag just add a mouseout and mousedown to call both functions.

```
function mouseFunction() {

document.getElementById('filters').style.transform = "scale(1)";

}
function mouse2Function() {

document.getElementById('filters').style.transform = "scale(0.9)";

}

<button onmouseout = "mouseFunction();" onmousedown = "mouse2Function();"id = "filters">Filters</button>
```